# How to change a website's web root in Visual Studio 2022? (+ complications)

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

*Using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022 17.2.4, Angular 16.15.1.*

I created my project using `ng new [project-name] etc`...
Project has configuration files in root folder then website in /src folder.
I opened my project in Visual Studio 2022 through `File > Open > WebSite...`.
Visual Studio added a Web.config file in the root folder.

Problem: When I run the site from Visual Studio, the site opens at
**http://localhost:61500/src/index.html**

I do not want to use full blown IIS or such for this project. I would like to configure the project so that VS open it at **http://localhost:61500/index.html**   (without the /src level)
Or even better would be: **http://localhost:61500/**

Is it possible to do this from current situation ?

---

By searching the Internet I find suggestions that imply using a different project type or IIS, but haven't found the solution for this precise case.

---

Tried: I tried adding the following which I found in another StackOverflow question, but this didn't change a thing.

```
  <system.web>
    (...)
      <urlMappings enabled="true">
          <add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/src/index.html" />
      </urlMappings>

  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect everything to root" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/src/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

---

Tried: I tried adding the following which I found in another StackOverflow question. The site was launched once at **http://localhost:61500/** with a server error.
Now that I have removed this. The site will ALWAYS start at **http://localhost:61500/** with a "*HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden*" error. (Is there some cache that can be removed ?) **http://localhost:61500/src/index.html** gets the *Forbidden* error as well.

```
<system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://localhost:61500/" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
```

---

Edit: Even after deleting Web.config and other Visual Studio related folders and deleting the solution files from "C:\Users[UserName\source\repos" and reopening the project as a fresh new "website" ... launching from Visual Studio goes to **http://localhost:61500/** with *HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden* response.

---

Edit: Very weird...

- I created a "simple" website on a random location, opened it as a website in Visual Studio, it worked fine, it didn't get the *HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden* error.
- I move renamed my Angular 2+ project and moved the files from this tiny website to it's loction, opened it as a website in Visual Studio, it worked fine, it didn't get the *HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden* error.
- I completely deleted my Angular project (I had not written anything in it yet anyway) and regerated it completely from the command that is mentionned above. I opened it as a website in Visual Studio, and *HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden* error.

So it seems like there is I-don't-know-what in Visual Studio "debugging" IIS that recognises this path + file structure and that bring back *HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden* error. This is very confusing to me.

*Plus* Right now I'm wondering if this Angular project can actually work when "opened as a website" where node.js is not involved... but this is a project to learn Angular anyway so it might as well not work on first try.

---

**I gave up on trying to solve these issues in Visual Studio alone.**
As **workaround**, I configured the local site in XAMPP and in Visual Studio > Right Click on the project > Property Pages > Start Options > Start URL & Use custom server > (entered the http://+[local domain to the configured site]).
(Not sur yet if everything will be OK for Angular as I'm still at the very beginning of the tutorial.)

Edit: Workaround part 2: I now realised it was wrong to try to point the website to /src  since it's for source code (yes I'm tired) but I also realised that Visual Studio never actually generated compiled website... despite writing that compilation was successful... or where it is?
I now use command `ng build` to compile site, pointed the local domain to [[project-path]\dist[project-name]\ and first "Hello Word" worked (displaying `title` at `<app-root></app-root>`).
Not sure if Visual Studio is still useful in this case, I might as well use Notepad/++ at this point...

But if someone has solutions to the initial problems... you're still welcome.

Comment: Why not just use `ng serve`?

Comment: Thank you, I will check what is ng serve and how it works next time I work on this.

Comment: @saravanapriyan: I tried `ng serve [project]` but that does nothing. I read that I should first run `npm i`, I realised that `npm i` has to be run from the project directory, but yet even after this, `ng serve [project]` does nothing. I think that I will be fine with XAMPP for now with this learning-project ... unless `ng serve` comes with some specific debug/log or something?

Comment: I just realised that `ng serve` is more than a replacement for XAMPP but also listen to changes for rebuilt... It's working now. Thank you.